# Two users logged in when connected to internet

Tags: security

I am on Debian 12.5.

I am worried, because on my system I always see two users logged in immediately after I enable internet connection! Otherwise I can only see one user logged in.

Could this be a security breach?

What can I do? I changed my passwords and removed `~/.ssh` and `/root/.ssh` folders. However, I can still see the second user.

---

This is how it looks like when I am connected on internet *(users are the same)*:

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> users
ziga ziga

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> ps -ef | grep ziga
avahi        615       1  0 00:11 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [ziga--workstation-2.local]
ziga         846       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
ziga         847     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
ziga         862     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:06 /usr/bin/pipewire
ziga         863     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/wireplumber
ziga         864     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:07 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
ziga         865     839  0 00:13 tty1     00:09:24 /usr/bin/sway
ziga         871     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
ziga         915       1  0 00:13 tty1     00:00:00 swaybg -o * -i /home/ziga/Dropbox/galerija/wallpapers/217.jpg -m fill
ziga         922       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c kanshi
ziga         924     922  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 kanshi
ziga         926       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c mako
ziga         927     926  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 mako
ziga         942       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c sleep 1 && waybar
ziga         959     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
ziga         973     942  0 00:13 ?        00:06:44 waybar
ziga         982     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
ziga         988     982  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus
ziga         989     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
ziga         996     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
ziga        1039       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c foot
ziga        1040    1039  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 foot
ziga        1041    1040  0 00:13 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
ziga        1062       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c foot
ziga        1063    1062  0 00:13 ?        00:01:26 foot
ziga        1064    1063  0 00:13 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash
ziga        1109    1064  0 00:13 pts/1    00:02:31 iwctl
ziga        1483       1  0 00:14 ?        00:00:00 sh -c foot
ziga        1484    1483  0 00:14 ?        00:00:00 foot
ziga        1485    1484  0 00:14 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
ziga        1671       1  0 00:15 ?        00:00:00 sh -c firefox
ziga        1672    1671  2 00:15 ?        00:24:14 firefox-esr
ziga        1677       1  0 00:15 tty1     00:00:26 Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -core -listenfd 30 -listenfd 32 -wm 93
ziga        1752    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -prefsLen 30382 -prefMapSize 240978 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {0efa8332-696e-4fc4-b9b8-f0f4e5c51969} 1672 true socket
ziga        1795    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 30458 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {e81d8447-3aea-4528-82a8-43c2a8894759} 1672 true tab
ziga        1841    1672 17 00:15 ?        03:25:55 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 36008 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {ba2bf5bd-158b-4688-9445-a7a0329e1d86} 1672 true tab
ziga        1899    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32154 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {4dc83a34-955e-4ffa-ba09-3f24f54b34d1} 1672 true tab
ziga        1990    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:22 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32154 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {b3de07aa-4c30-44ce-8525-f6b2502294b7} 1672 true tab
ziga        2481    1672  0 00:16 ?        00:01:19 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 9 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32154 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {69e2faea-4576-4d2e-b7cb-9125486845b4} 1672 true tab
ziga        5382    1672  0 00:29 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -prefsLen 36129 -prefMapSize 240978 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {c53be05e-bec7-4efe-8c3b-15a11a8fa608} 1672 true rdd
ziga        5384    1672  0 00:29 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -sandboxingKind 0 -prefsLen 36129 -prefMapSize 240978 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {05ba81a3-89b4-40d3-9594-191814bcad8e} 1672 true utility
ziga        7291    1672  0 00:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 21 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32220 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {3785424e-6154-49b7-afb7-60c4697d2e58} 1672 true tab
ziga        7332    1672  0 00:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 22 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32220 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {b3d8cb12-84a8-4f60-bf6b-08878e1ee062} 1672 true tab
ziga        7585    1672  0 00:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 23 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32220 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {166be087-44ec-44ab-aac3-74646835cdaf} 1672 true tab
ziga      243557       1  0 19:38 ?        00:00:00 sh -c foot
ziga      243558  243557  0 19:38 ?        00:00:00 foot
ziga      243559  243558  0 19:38 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/bash
ziga      243802  243559  0 19:40 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ef
ziga      243803  243559  0 19:40 pts/4    00:00:00 grep ziga
```

I had an idea. I used the previous command but outputed into file `1`. Then I removed internet connection and I repeated this command while outputting to file `2`. IFinally I used `git diff` to see where are the differences...

```
┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> ps -ef | grep ziga > 1

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/2
  └─> ip link set wlan0 down

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> ps -ef | grep ziga > 2 

┌───┐
│ $ │ ziga > ziga--workstation > ~ 
└─┬─┘ /dev/pts/4
  └─> git diff --no-index 1 2
diff --git a/1 b/2
index 3b57401..cec24ad 100644
--- a/1
+++ b/2
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ ziga         926       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c mako
 ziga         927     926  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 mako
 ziga         942       1  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c sleep 1 && waybar
 ziga         959     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
-ziga         973     942  0 00:13 ?        00:06:44 waybar
+ziga         973     942  0 00:13 ?        00:06:45 waybar
 ziga         982     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
 ziga         988     982  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 11 --address=unix:path=/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus
 ziga         989     846  0 00:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ ziga        1672    1671  2 00:15 ?        00:24:36 firefox-esr
 ziga        1677       1  0 00:15 tty1     00:00:28 Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -core -listenfd 30 -listenfd 32 -wm 93
 ziga        1752    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -prefsLen 30382 -prefMapSize 240978 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {0efa8332-696e-4fc4-b9b8-f0f4e5c51969} 1672 true socket
 ziga        1795    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 30458 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {e81d8447-3aea-4528-82a8-43c2a8894759} 1672 true tab
-ziga        1841    1672 17 00:15 ?        03:25:55 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 36008 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {ba2bf5bd-158b-4688-9445-a7a0329e1d86} 1672 true tab
+ziga        1841    1672 17 00:15 ?        03:26:01 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 36008 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {ba2bf5bd-158b-4688-9445-a7a0329e1d86} 1672 true tab
 ziga        1899    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32154 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {4dc83a34-955e-4ffa-ba09-3f24f54b34d1} 1672 true tab
 ziga        1990    1672  0 00:15 ?        00:00:22 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32154 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {b3de07aa-4c30-44ce-8525-f6b2502294b7} 1672 true tab
 ziga        2481    1672  0 00:16 ?        00:01:33 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr -contentproc -childID 9 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 32154 -prefMapSize 240978 -jsInitLen 240916 -parentBuildID 20240212204114 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser {69e2faea-4576-4d2e-b7cb-9125486845b4} 1672 true tab
@@ -45,5 +45,5 @@ ziga        7585    1672  0 00:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox
 ziga      243557       1  0 19:38 ?        00:00:00 sh -c foot
 ziga      243558  243557  0 19:38 ?        00:00:00 foot
 ziga      243559  243558  0 19:38 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/bash
-ziga      244086  243559  0 19:41 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ef
-ziga      244087  243559  0 19:41 pts/4    00:00:00 grep ziga
+ziga      244166  243559  0 19:41 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ef
+ziga      244167  243559  0 19:41 pts/4    00:00:00 grep ziga
```

To me only firefox looks suspicious.

Comment: what name does the other user have? what do you see if you do `ps -ef | grep OtherUserName` ? There are probably better techniques to see what "they" are doing, (I'll let the pros post about those) but `ps ..` will get you started.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command(s) (and output from the commands) you type that show you two users that are logged in.

Comment: @shellter I did that. Any clues?

Comment: Is `ziga` a user name you don't recognize? (your name here is very similar). If not, then look to see if there is a $HOME/ziga directory. Then you also need to figure out why/where all the firefox processes are being displayed (multiple FF processes are normal, as each tab in FF makes a process). (Do you use FF as your primary browser?) Then search for those "weird" commands, `mako, foot, waybar, kanshi`. Are they all in the same directory? What does `users` from the cmd-ine return?  I'm (obviously) not a security expert. I'm not sure what to do after this. Good show updating your question! ..

Comment: Reply by adding and cmd output to your questions at the bottom in a section labeled **Edit** and the leave a comment with "question update" as the first part.

Comment: @shellter I recognize all processes and I start them manually using my user `ziga`. Everything looks fine... However, I still don't understand why two users!? I am using `dhclient`and I figured out that it creates the second user! :S

Comment: Hmm. not clear then : What is the evidence that you *"always see two users logged in immediately"* ? If you don't see the 2nd user in your `ps` listings then how do you know it is there. Actual cmd and output (depersonalized) would have been the place to start when posting this question (-;! (Did you look for dir `$HOME/otherrUsername` ? Are you OK with `mako, foot, waybar and kanshi` running on your system? If `users` didn't return anything, then look at `/etc/passwd` and see if you that gives you any clue. There will likely be a bunch of system names like `mail, news, uucp,` etc, etc.

Comment: You would like to check this: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566932/what-is-the-avahi-daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566932/what-is-the-avahi-daemon)